# bootstrap 4 pills don't de-active after clicking once

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make vertically aligned bootstrap pills with custom styling for my website.

But anyhow when the pills once active (by clicking on it) it doesn't deactivate by clicking the other tab next, as a result, I can't change my tab correctly.

And the 3rd to 6th pills don't work anything.

**DEMO**

```css
.h-bstfecture-ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.h-bstfecture-ul li{
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30PX;
  padding-right: 45PX;
  padding-left: 20PX;
  border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.h-bstfecture-ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}


.h-bstfecture-ul li img{
  max-height: 26px;
  max-width: 26px;
  /*fill: #222222;
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);*/
}

.h-bstfecture-ul li:hover a{
  color: #FFC000;
}

.bestservice-pillstitle{
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bestservice-pills-paragraph{
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.bestservice-pillscontent ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.bestservice-pillscontent ul li{
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ylw-tik{
  width: 12px;
}

.our-service-title{
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;

}

.our-service-title:before, .our-service-title:after{
  content:" ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #FFC000;
}


.our-service-subtitle{
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center m-0 mb-5">
    <div class="our-service-head">
      <p class="our-service-title text-center">Our Best Features</p>
      <p class="our-service-subtitle text-center px-3">
        Nulla ullamcorper bibendum orci, ac tempor nisl lacinia quis. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="bestservice-pills col-xl-2 mx-3 p-0">
      <ul class="h-bstfecture-ul m-0 p-0 nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <li class="row m-0 nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
          <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-1.svg"></div>
          <a href="#" class="ml-2">Efficient Inspection</a>
        </li>

        <li class="row m-0 nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">
          <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-2.svg"></div>
          <a href="#" class="ml-2">Employee Safety</a>
        </li>

        <li class="row m-0 nav-link" id="3rd-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#3rd" role="tab" aria-controls="3rd" aria-selected="false">
          <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-3.svg"></div>
          <a href="#" class="ml-2">Industrial Automation</a>
        </li>

        <li class="row m-0 nav-link" id="4th-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#4th" role="tab" aria-controls="4th" aria-selected="false">
          <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-4.svg"></div>
          <a href="#" class="ml-2">Employee Feedback</a>
        </li>

        <li class="row m-0 nav-link" id="5th-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#5th" role="tab" aria-controls="5th" aria-selected="false">
          <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-5.svg"></div>
          <a href="#" class="ml-2">Live Data Monitoring</a>
        </li>

        <li class="row m-0 nav-link" id="6th-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#6th" role="tab" aria-controls="6th" aria-selected="false">
          <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-6.svg"></div>
          <a href="#" class="ml-2">Technological Support</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-5 border border-primary mx-1 p-0 tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">


      <!-- 1st pill -->             
      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
        <p>1st</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
        <p>2nd</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="3rd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="3rd-tab">
        <p>3rd</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="4th" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="4th-tab">
        <p>4th</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="5th" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="5th-tab">
        <p>5th</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="6th" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="6th-tab">
        <p>6th</p>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-3 border border-primary mx-1 p-0">
      <div class="m-0">
        <img src="images/best fecture-1.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?

**problem's file link-**
https://github.com/Kanchon-Gharami/problems-share-in-git.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is basicly that you are trying to use `pill` on elements that are not `a` tag.

As you can see in Bootstrap [javascript-behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior), all the examples are set with `pill` on `a` tag.

Plus, in [Via JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript), there is the code below:

```js
$('#myTab a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

This is probably a similar code used to manage `pill`. So basicaly it is based on `a` tag.

Below, you find a light demo from your code that works fine with pills on `a` tag + href pointing to the right `id` (I let you optimize the blue background to the right way):

```css
.h-bstfecture-ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.h-bstfecture-ul li{
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30PX;
  padding-right: 45PX;
  padding-left: 20PX;
  border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.h-bstfecture-ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}


.h-bstfecture-ul li img{
  max-height: 26px;
  max-width: 26px;
  /*fill: #222222;
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);*/
}

.h-bstfecture-ul li:hover a{
  color: #FFC000;
}

.bestservice-pillstitle{
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bestservice-pills-paragraph{
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.bestservice-pillscontent ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.bestservice-pillscontent ul li{
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ylw-tik{
  width: 12px;
}

.our-service-title{
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;

}

.our-service-title:before, .our-service-title:after{
  content:" ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #FFC000;
}


.our-service-subtitle{
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center m-0 mb-5">
    <div class="our-service-head">
      <p class="our-service-title text-center">Our Best Features</p>
      <p class="our-service-subtitle text-center px-3">
        Nulla ullamcorper bibendum orci, ac tempor nisl lacinia quis. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="bestservice-pills col-xl-2 mx-3 p-0">
      <ul class="h-bstfecture-ul m-0 p-0 nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <li class="row m-0 nav-item">
          <a href="#v-pills-home" class="ml-2 nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
            <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-1.svg"></div>
            Efficient Inspection
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="row m-0 nav-item">
          <a href="#v-pills-profile" class="ml-2 nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">
            <div style="width: 35px;"><img src="icons/our-best-feacture-2.svg"></div>
            Employee Safety
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-5 border border-primary mx-1 p-0 tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">


      <!-- 1st pill -->             
      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
        <p>1st</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
        <p>2nd</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="3rd" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="3rd-tab">
        <p>3rd</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="4th" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="4th-tab">
        <p>4th</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="5th" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="5th-tab">
        <p>5th</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bestservice-pillscontent tab-pane fade" id="6th" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="6th-tab">
        <p>6th</p>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-3 border border-primary mx-1 p-0">
      <div class="m-0">
        <img src="images/best fecture-1.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, that means I need to change the full structure, thanks a lot for finding out the problem.